# Integral of a fraction in square root.

Tags: integration

How to perform this type of indefinite integrals?
$$\int dy\frac{\sqrt{y^{2}+1}}{\sqrt{y^2 + a^2}}$$
where $y$ and $a$ are both real.

Comment: I am afraid that this would lead to some elliptic integrals

Comment: @Claude Further elaboration or a promising direction would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt%28y%5E2%2B1%29%2Fsqrt%28y%5E2%2Ba%5E2%29

Comment: @Xavier I think that Claude wanted to hint that there is no direction that you would find promosing unless you are familiar with elliptic integrals. Or in other words, this function does not have a primitive in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: By the way, **Welcome to the site !**